# Store Scores in an array , shared preference or database?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently assigning numbers to an object for each round of a game. for instance a,b,c,d,e.  I save this object in an array and then later use this array to build a recycler view for each new round, so you can scroll through all the rounds and see how you did.  What I'm having trouble doing are 2 things.  each round you're going to get either 10 * what is in a or -10 * what is in a.

1. Should I do the math on that and store it in the object, or is it better to get a from the object and do the math on it then?
2. How should i total the score?  should i run the array through a loop each time a round is submitted and total a, or is there a better/easier way to update your total score when each round is submitted?

Here's my object class

```
 class Rounds (
     var rn: Int,
     var t1score: Int,
     var t2score: Int,
 )
```

and my function

```
  private fun funScoreRound(rounds: ArrayList<Rounds>, rn: Int) {

    //rn = round, t1score = team one score for the round, t2score = team two score for the round
    var rn++
    var t1score = t1bid * 10
    var t2score = t2bid * 10



    rounds.add(Rounds(rn, 1score, t2score))
```

I tried using

```
 var onetotal = rounds.sumby { t1score }
 var twototal = rounds.sumby { t2score }
```

but that does not total how i expected.  Just really looking for what the best practice is, if it's to save it to a shared preference and then every time a round is submitted resave it and reupdate the text field, or ...

Comment: I don't fully understand what your issue is, however, I'm pretty sure you don't need a database / shared prefs for what you're doing. Databases are for persisting data between app launches, shared preferences for keeping a few bits of usually app settings. Maybe a highscore. You should not need to save anything to disk as long as the app runs. Somethings wrong in your code if If you need to do that. Wrt letting objects do things or  do things on them: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html for example is one opinion

Comment: @zapl so you would generate the total using an array loop or you would try and use the sumby function?

Comment: I guess you should ultimately have some form of persistence because games that lose your progress are annoying. But I don't understand your sumBy issue or the way the scoring works so I can't comment on what a good solution is

Comment: @zapl that's fair.  I was just hoping to try and get a general idea of how I should be doing it and figure it out on my own. Sounds like I'm on the right path.  I'll try and figure out why my sumby seems not to be totaling correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure of what you are asking, but i am trying answer the question you have listed out.

1. You can construct an custom class object to store all rounds information and do the math inside, lets say `MatchSummary` or any name you like. By doing this, you can easily manage each match / round you have.

   ```
    data class MatchSummary(private val rounds: ArrayList<Rounds>) {
        fun getTeamOneTotalScore(): Int = rounds.sumBy{ t1score }
        fun getTeamTwoTotalScore(): Int = rounds.sumBy{ t2score }
        fun getAllRounds(): ArrayList<Rounds> = rounds
        fun getCurrentRound(): Int = rounds.size
        fun getRoundsInfo(index: Int): Rounds = rounds.get(index)
        fun addRounds(t1bid: Int, t2bid: Int) {
            // do the math here
            let t1RoundScore = t1bid * 10
            let t2RoundScore = t2bid * 10
            rounds.add(Rounds(rounds.size+1, t1RoundScore, t2RoundScore))
        }
    }
   ```
2. `sumBy` function should be the function you are looking for. Could you please tell what difficulties you have in using it?
3. First of all, three of them can co-exist. They have different purpose and usage. Storing inside an array (memory) is the typical way for your application to operate correctly. You cannot persist the data after application closed. 
   Storing inside sharedPreference or database are ways to persist data upon application close and launch. The difference is the size of the data you want to persist. SharePreference is made for developer to save the user preferences / settings which is tiny. 
   Database is made for developer to persist the data will be shown to user which is larger in size. Apart from that, you can share the data between different apps.

Hope i can provide some idea/hints of what you are trying to do. Happy coding!

Reference:
[SharePreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)
[Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Comment: This is very helpful!  I think I have the right idea, store it in an array and if I want to persist it consider sharedprefs and/or database.  You've answered both questions I had.  Essentially, no need to store the values in the array that can be calculated and sumby is a good option for temporary calculation of values but does not persist.  Which should be fine in my case, maybe v2 i'll add a save function, but should generally not be necessary for me.  Thanks!